# How to SELECT from multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I have a lot of tables with the same `_ips` endings. Example:

```
first-domain.com_ips
secons-domain.com_ips
...
```

I'm trying to get `UNION` result table which will contains all rows from all `_ips` tables. For this I use:

```
SELECT id, expirationDate FROM `first-domain.com_ips` WHERE isBlocked = 1
UNION
SELECT id, expirationDate FROM `secons-domain.com_ips` WHERE isBlocked = 1
...;
```

I have an array which consists of domain names. So I'm looking for a way to use this domain array in SQL query. Maybe something like we use with SELECT. Example:

```
const ids = [3, 4, 6, 8];
const query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (' + ids.join() + ')';
```

Is there a way to use array for tables names in SQL? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Don't store a separate table for each domain.  Include the domain as a column in a single table.

Comment: If there is any chance that the values from the `ids` array could come from the outside, unsterilized, then you'll want to use a prepared statement to build your query.

Comment: Please take a look at my posted answer, mark it as accepted answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using dynamic queries and regexps:

This dynamic query does what you want :

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT * FROM `',
      TABLE_NAME,
      '`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
WHERE
  `TABLE_NAME` REGEXP '_ips$'
INTO @sql;

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This query gives two outputs, first is the final SQL query string which looks like :

```
SELECT * FROM `first-domain.com_ips` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `second-domain.com_ips`
```

and the other output is the actual data from all tables, if you want only the final data, you can remove this statement:

```
SELECT @sql;
```

Comment: Will try it in nearest time, when get to my computer. Thank you!

Comment: yes, it works! but could you explain where TABLE_NAME comes from? And what is INTO and @sql?

Comment: TABLE_NAME is a placeholder variable, that gets its value from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`  , which holds all table names in your DB, so when you run this, it replaces it with the actual table name, putting a where clause defining regular expression  "REGEXP '_ips$' that means, get all tables from table list that ends with '_ips'. The @sql is also variable that the select puts its result to, so it holds your final query string.